# How to edit root privliged files mounted locally using sshfs

Tags: linux, sshfs, ubuntu-16.04

I have a server running ubuntu 16.04 (same OS is on my local machine). I then mount remote file system on my local machine using command

```
sshfs -o allow_other user@remote_server.com :/ /home/local_user/remote/ -p 22
```

Now everything works fine except I cannot edit root privileged files like those residing in /etc. How can I edit those files using editors on my local machine like gedit.

Answer (score 2):

This procedure work only if on the remote server you can `sudo` without password (see below for configuration of this).

#### On the remote server

create a file `/opt/sudo-ftp-server`:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec sudo /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server "$@"
```

and `chmod +x` it.

To allow sudo without password for just the sftp-server command and for a just specific user, create a file `/etc/sudoers.d/start-sftp-server-wo-password`:

```
theusername ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

#### On the local server

edit `/etc/fuse.conf` and add `user_allow_other`.

mount with:

```
sshfs -o allow_other -o sftp_server=/opt/sudo-sftp-server hostname:remote_path local_path
```

Answer (score 0):

mount as root

```
sshfs -o allow_other root@remote_server.com :/ /home/local_user/remote/ -p 22
```

Comment: mounting as root is not an option as root account is disabled due to security reasons

Comment: then the story ends

Answer (score 0):

If you connect as `user@remote_server.com`, you inherit the privileges of `user`, i.e. you can edit those files, that `user` has write access to.

To fix this, you need to connect as a user, that has these write privileges - this might need to be root.

The best (and usual) way around this is to edit these files on the remote server via sudo.